# Is it possible to set a variable as a positive one in the whole notebook?

Tags: numerical-integration, assumptions, complex

I'm having issues during integration due to the fact that *Mathematica* doesn't know if an undefined variable is positive or not (it gives me complexes which bothers me in the end).

For example I do this:

```
yy[x_, t_] = aa[t]*(Cos[0.1*x]-Cosh[0.1 x]-Sin[0.1 x]+Sinh[0.1 x])

Integrate[D[yy[x, t], t]^2, {x, 0, 18}]
```

gives me:

> `(10.1601 + 0.I) aa'[t]²`

while the `0.I` shouldn't be here. By using:

```
Integrate[D[yy[x, t], t]^2, {x, 0, 18}, Assumptions -> aa[t] > 0]
```

I get rid of the imaginary part but this has to be done cell by cell.

Then comes my questions, is it possible to define, in that case, `aa[t]` as a posivite variable in the whole notebook and not cell by cell?
Note that in this expample the `I` is not bothering at all, but with concrete numbers it messes everything up, even by using `Chop`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can modify the global system variable `$Assumptions`, to get the effect you want:

```
$Assumptions = aa[t] > 0
```

Then

```
Integrate[D[yy[x, t], t]^2, {x, 0, 18}]
```

> ```
> 10.1601 Derivative[1][aa][t]^2
> ```

This may, however, be somewhat error-prone. Here is how I'd do this with *local environments*. This is a generator for a local environment:

```
createEnvironment[assumptions_] :=
   Function[code,
     Block[{$Assumptions = $Assumptions && assumptions}, code],
     HoldAll];
```

We now create one:

```
$Assumptions = True;
env = createEnvironment[aa[t] > 0];
```

To use it, prefix the intergal with it:

```
env@Integrate[D[yy[x,t],t]^2,{x,0,18}]
```

> ```
>  10.1601 (aa^\[Prime])[t]^2
> ```

This is a bit more work since you have to prefix, but it is safer.

Comment: Thanks a lot!I've been looking around on google for ages, and you replied me within 3 mins, thanks!

Comment: @Öskå Have a look at the addition I made with environments. This is an intermediate variant - more convenient than setting `Assumptions` in `Integrate` explicitly, and safer than modifying `$Assumptions` globally.

Comment: I did, & edited comment too, once again, thank you.