# Problem with general assumptions

Tags: assumptions

I hope I am not to redundant with my questions. As part of solving a physical problem, I want to assume once and for all that all my variables and parameters are real, positive and finite.

Is it possible make such assumptions for all *Mathematica* functions?

I tried this piece of code I found on the forum:

```
$Assumptions = Element[_, Reals] && {_ ∈ Reals} && {_} > 0;
```

But still, `Sign` does not aways return 1, `Minimize` does not treat all parameters as negative, etc.

Comment: Would [that](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6397/is-it-possible-to-set-a-variable-as-a-positive-one-in-the-whole-notebook) be useful?

Answer (score 4):

Your assigning a pattern to `$Assumptions` won't work because the  *Mathematica* assumption mechanism is simply not geared to accept patterns. It is not based on pattern matching. To get `$Assumptions` to behave as you say you want it to, you would have to use the system hook [`$NewSymbol`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/$NewSymbol.html) and do something like what is discussed in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4320778).

But even that won't do what you really want, because only functions that take the option `Assumptions` pay attention to `$Assumptions`. The mechanism is that such functions evaluate `Assumptions :> $Assumptions` when the option is not explicitly given. Only a rather small number of *Mathematica* take this option.