# Assumption on the range of a function

Tags: functions, simplifying-expressions, assumptions

I'm using value-defined function as set of parameter, i.e.

```
f[1] ===> first parameter
f[2] ===> second parameter
f[3] ===> third parameter
```

etc.
I would like to tell Mathematica that all these parameters  are positive. I tried something like

```
FullSimplify[Abs[f[1]],Assumptions-> {f[x_]>0}]
```

and I get

```
Abs[f[1]]
```

instead of the desired

```
f[1]
```

Of course here I posted just an example, the function I have to simplify in my case is much more complicated.
How can I do?

Comment: Have you tried creating a list of assumptions like `Thread[Table[f[i], {i, fmin, fmax}] > 0]`?

Comment: Interestingly using `f[1] > 0` in `Assumptions` does work. Doesn't pattern matching work here, and if so, why?

Comment: Of course this is a solution but in my program I don't know the range of the parameters. I want to tell Mathematica that *every* value of the function is positive.

Comment: Do you have to define the functions in `f[n_]`? when such things matter I try to define them in $x_m,..,x_0,..x_n$ instead.

Comment: Of course it's possible, but in this casa how can I tell Mathematica $x_i>0$ forall $i$? Can you give me an example?

Comment: @MaPo Well I don't know your full code, normally I'd define all $x_i$ in one variable, otherwise you might be able to pattern match.

Comment: @MaPo A way I see (not sure whether it fits your need in your more general case) would be to define an `UpValue` for `f`, either with `f /: Abs[fun : f[_]] := fun` or with `Abs[fun : f[_]] ^:= fun`. This will evaluate `Abs[f[1]]` to `f[1]`, for instance, without the need of using `Assumptions` and `FullSimplify`.

Comment: Related: [(6182)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6182/121), [(42607)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/42607/121), [(58271)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/58271/121), [(67343)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/67343/121), [(79301)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/79301/121), [(79756)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/79756/121), [(94983)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/94983/121)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**EDIT**: Simplified per suggestion from @BobHanlon.

This constructs assumptions by finding all occurrences of pattern `f[_]` in the expression being simplified:

```
FullSimplify[#, Cases[#, v : f[_] :> v > 0, Infinity]] &[
 Abs[f[f[1]]] + Abs[f[x]]]

(* f[x] + f[f[1]] *)
```

Comment: +1 Or more succinctly:  `Simplify[#, Cases[#, v : f[_] :> v > 0, Infinity]] &[
 Abs[f[f[1]]] + Abs[f[x]]]`

Comment: I find it somewhat surprising that Mathematica doesn't have support for a more concise way of expressing this.

Comment: @mikado I wouldn't be surprised if I there would actually be a way, but I wouldn't be aware of it. Thankfully the above form is not that long, just slightly inelegant.